# R: Multiple Linear Regression error

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, read.table

I am having hard times running the `lm()` function and understanding the error.

So, my script is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env/ Rscript

meteodata <- read.table("/path/to/dataset.txt", header=T)
meteodata
summary(meteodata)


plot(meteodata)

lmodel <- lm(temperature~altitude+sea.distance, data=meteodata)
```

And the console output is this:

```
temperature station.id latitude longtitude sea.distance altitude
1         20,1         S1      0,5        0,5          0,5        0
2         20,5         S1      0,5        0,5          0,5        0
3         19,3         S1      0,5        0,5          0,5        0
4         18,6         S1      0,5        0,5          0,5        0
5         21,5         S1      0,5        0,5          0,5        0
6         17,1         S2      3,5        2,5          1,5      200
7         18,3         S2      3,5        2,5          1,5      200
8         16,8         S2      3,5        2,5          1,5      200
9         17,5         S2      3,5        2,5          1,5      200
10        16,4         S2      3,5        2,5          1,5      200
11        18,4         S3      2,5        3,5          0,5      100
12        19,1         S3      2,5        3,5          0,5      100
13        18,9         S3      2,5        3,5          0,5      100
14        17,8         S3      2,5        3,5          0,5      100
15        17,6         S3      2,5        3,5          0,5      100
16        15,1         S4        4          0            4      400
17        15,5         S4        4          0            4      400
18        15,0         S4        4          0            4      400
19        14,9         S4        4          0            4      400
20        15,8         S4        4          0            4      400
  temperature station.id latitude longtitude sea.distance    altitude  
 14,9   : 1   S1:5       0,5:5    0  :5      0,5:10       Min.   :  0  
 15,0   : 1   S2:5       2,5:5    0,5:5      1,5: 5       1st Qu.: 75  
 15,1   : 1   S3:5       3,5:5    2,5:5      4  : 5       Median :150  
 15,5   : 1   S4:5       4  :5    3,5:5                   Mean   :175  
 15,8   : 1                                               3rd Qu.:250  
 16,4   : 1                                               Max.   :400  
 (Other):14                                                            
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : - not meaningful for factors
```

I  ve read some similar questions here and there but i still can't figure out what i am doing wrong.
I need `temperature` as my response y variable to be calculated by the independent *x1,x2* `altitude` and  `sea.distance` variables.

Any help will be appreciated, just try to be specific. Thanks in advance

Comment: One or more of the variables in your formula is a factor. You should have used dec="," in your read input sttement because those numbers are displaying with commas and that's a sure sign they are not "numeric".

Comment: You seem to have commas (,) instead of dots (.) as decimal separators in you numeric fields, such as temperature. This can be easily rectified if you add argument `dec=","` in your `read.table()` command. In your case, R takes the intended numbers as categorical variables (factors).

Comment: @Roland that fixed it.  Please expand your comment into an answer so i can accept  it if you will

Comment: @JTT ok thanks for explaining the error. i only cared in using `"\t"` while arraying my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R uses `.` as the decimal separator. Your data uses `,` and R interprets the data as characters, which are made factor variables by default. Use `dec=","` to tell `read.table` that the data is numeric with `,` as the decimal separator.